# Angular2 remembering state

Tags: angular

From my Angular2 framework, I can make a HTTP call. When I make a call, it triggers a spinner in a button to show the user something is happening. How can I make it so that if I refresh the page or go to another component and come back the spinner still shows? It needs to keep spinning until it gets a response from the API server (success or not)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Service` they keep the state when you change pages. When you go back to that `Component` you can just ask the service if the HTTP request is finished, if it isn't then just keep spinning.

I used this video to understand `Service`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9GTPGtDrxU